# Only allow scrolling to stop on certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've tried searching to see if there's already a question about this but can't find anything - so apologies if this is in fact a duplicate!

I've seen on some websites a feature where, when scrolling, the scroll stop point is forced to stop at a specific element rather than just wherever the user actually stopped scrolling.

I imagine this can be achieved via jQuery, but can't seem to find any documentation or help articles about it.

So, here's some example HTML...

```
<div id="one" class="block"></div>
<div id="two" class="block"></div>
<div id="three" class="block"></div>
```

With this as the CSS...

```
#one {
background: red;
}

#two {
background: green;
}

#three {
background: yellow;
}

.block {
width: 200px;
height: 100vh;
}
```

And what I'm looking to achieve is that when the user scrolls their browser from div 'one' to div 'two', once they've started scrolling over div 'two' and they then stop scrolling the browser automatically jumps them so that they see div 'two' in full, rather than a bit of the bottom of div 'one' and then most of div 'two' - I've definitely seen it done before but no idea how!

I hope this makes sense, and thanks in advance for any help or insight anyone can offer...

Comment: Are you looking for 'scrolljacking'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember too well, but I guess there are many ways to achieve what you want. One thing that came to my mind is to wrap around your divs and make a separate hidden div with full height. I did this adhoc solution below:

Once scroll approaches a threshold, I move to the div I should be looking at and vice versa. Here is a working solution [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/vrhjce2L/76/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="phantom"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="one" class="block"></div>
<div id="two" class="block"></div>
<div id="three" class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#one {
background: red;
}

#two {
background: green;
}

#three {
background: yellow;
}

.block {
width: 200px;
height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
}

#phantom {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
!function(){
    //the array of divs
    var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("block")),            count = divs.length,
        wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
      phantom = document.getElementById("phantom"),
      //the speed of scroll
      scrollStep = 5,
      //total length of phantom div
            totalLength = Array.prototype.slice.call(wrapper.children).reduce(function(ac,d,i,a){return ac += d.clientHeight},0),
      //store the animation frame here
            currentFrame;
      //wrapper is overflow hidden
    wrapper.style.height = totalLength/count + "px";
  //phantom has full height
  phantom.style.height = totalLength + "px";
  //add listener for scroll
    window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
        //throttle the function
      if(this._busy){return};
        this._busy = true;
            var that = this;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
            that._busy = false;
                    var heightOfDocument = Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight),
            totalScroll = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop),
          //which element should we look at?
                    whichElement = Math.round(totalScroll/heightOfDocument*count);
          //if we are already around, don't do anything
          if(divs[whichElement]._current){
            return;
          } else {
            //cancel the last animation if any and start a new one
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(currentFrame);
            divs.forEach(function(d,i){delete d._current});
            moveTo(divs[whichElement]);
          }
      });
    },false);
  //helper function to linearly move to elements
    function moveTo(node){
            node._current = true;
            var top = node.offsetTop,
                    current = node.parentNode.scrollTop,
                    distance = top - current,
                    step = distance < 0 ? -scrollStep : scrollStep;
            if(Math.abs(distance) < scrollStep){
        node.parentNode.scrollTop = top;
                return;
      } else {
        node.parentNode.scrollTop += step;
      }
      //store the current frame
            currentFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                moveTo(node);
            });
    }
}();
```

You obviously need to attach 'resize' event to update the values of the totalLength and set the correct new length on wrapper and phantom. You can also implement a easing function to modify the scrolling behavior to your taste. I leave them to you as homework.